# CRM Dashboard List with Chart

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have added a list to the dashboard and would like the chart to appear next to the list without having to use up one of my 6 slots. There is an option to "Display Chart Selection" however when this is selected the chart isn't shown. The chart is only shown if I choose "Show Chart Only" in which case I lose the list.

[image]

In simple is there a way to display both Chart and List using up one slot on the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use to slots for this, there is no other way around it.

Thanks